# How to disable node editor edge panning?

Tags: node-editor, interface

After updating to Blender 3.0, I noticed that when you move nodes to the edge of the node editor window, the screen starts panning. I managed to disable this behaviour for the move(G) command but when adding a new node with shift+a, the panning still happens.

Video: https://i.imgur.com/131BSTV.mp4
How can I completely disable this panning behaviour?

Comment: Do you mean that the nodes move to the side when you add a new node to the node tree? Or is it something else?

Comment: @Timaroberts I have added a video of what happens.